# How to structure subtasks that are partially complete and to be worked on later for another dependency

Tags: organizational-structure, work-breakdown-structure

I can explain this question better with an analogy.

Suppose I am a uni student and I have a maths tutorial. For this tutorial, there is attendance, a tutorial sheet and some other things. For this tutorial to be complete, I just need to attend, but the tutorial sheet is worked on during the tutorial. It is not compulsory to complete this sheet yet, but will be later for a final test.

Let's say in this "Week 1 Tutorial" I complete 4/8 of the questions on the sheet and I can no longer devote any time today to work on it. Assuming there is a manager to report to (since this is an analogy after all), they want to know what I was working on today at 12:00 - 1:00, which was the tutorial sheet. This is displayed on a software calendar via assigning a start and finish time to tasks, so in this case, I have "Math Tutorial" from 12:00 - 1:00. Since it is incomplete and I am going to work on it later, I can't re-assign the times to work on the tutorial sheet since it has already got the times of 12:00 - 1:00 set for it. [image]

How can I understand this complication in a sort of tree-diagrammy kind of way so I can figure out what the subtasks are and dependencies are and the places that they exist in the main project of "Math 101"? This is the kind of diagram I was using to explain this, however it may not be very helpful nor the correct way to organise the issue.

Comment: "they want to know what I was working on today at 12:00 - 1:00" - sounds like you need to get a new hypothetical manager. That's a disgusting amount of micromangement!

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Your work breakdown structure is too high-level to map to person-hours. Your project plan does not conform to the [INVEST mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)). The requested reporting data you're being asked for can't be accurately measured or inferred from your node diagram.

In short, you need to re-plan the activities to map to the expected reporting structure, and then rebase your schedule based on the new plan. If you don't know how to do these things, then you should ask your teacher for assistance in either understanding the assignment more clearly or determining what part of the curriculum this was addressed in.

It would be unusual for a class to have an assignment where the information necessary to get a passing grade (NB: such grades are generally based on the teacher's lessons and expectations, not necessarily on how real-world practitioners would approach such problems) has not been provided as part of class instruction. Therefore, **opening a line of communication with your instructor** seems indicated.

### Analysis and Recommendations

Your "tree diagram" is functionally a high-level [work breakdown structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure) (WBS), with perhaps the intent of representing an [activity-on-node diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method#Visualizing_critical_path_schedule). In either case, it is *extremely* high level, and doesn't map well to person-hours or dates the way you might represent them on a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart). As a result, you can't report status or adjust schedule the way you're being asked to do so.

If you've addressed 4/8ths of the assignment sheet, then you can say you're 50% done with that particular task. However, **you may not even have enough information to estimate remaining time** unless you can assume *a priori* that the second half of the assignment sheet will take the same amount of time or effort to complete as the first half.

You can certainly report on the elapsed time since the beginning of the assignment and the remaining time until the due date. Pragmatically, those are your only two fixed points within the schedule.

For reporting purposes, and given the limited amount of information you have within your WBS and critical path diagram, you can only report on a few other items other than the start and end dates of the assignment:

1. How much "attendance" you have completed.
2. How much "attendance" remains.
3. How much of the worksheet is completed.
4. How much of the worksheet remains.

If you are expected to turn this into a Gantt chart with hourly labor increments, you will have to rebuild your plan in a way that's designed to map activities to an hourly calendar of some sort. You can then document or estimate the start and finish times of various things in a more detailed node graph, Gantt, or [PERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_evaluation_and_review_technique) chart based on known elements like when classes are held and scheduled vs. actual time spent on your worksheet. You may then need to estimate time remaining on the worksheet based on how much time each portion of the worksheet has taken and applying that to the number of remaining items, with whatever fudge factors you need to represent any changes in difficulty or your availability to work on the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are choosing not to decompose that sub task further so you can show the 100% completion of part of that sub task with a start date later for the other part of that sub task, then you simply report that you are x% complete, say 20%.  Then task is split on the schedule and will have a new start date for the next part of that task.  The hard part with knowledge work is determining the proper % complete but that's a different question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to poke deeper into David's premise that "If you are choosing not to decompose that sub task further".

Why aren't you splitting up those subtasks?

Now, there might well be a legitimate answer to that question. Or there might not be. It all depends on the situation.

But were I in your shoes, my first instinct would be to start splitting up tasks to be more atomic.

See the 'S' in [INVEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)).